# Events are independent or not independent in the following example?

Tags: probability, proof-verification, proof-explanation, independence, expected-value

Question. 
Let $X_1,X_2,X_3$    denote the outcomes of three rolls of a six-sided die. (I.e., each $X_i$   is uniformly distributed among ${1,2,3,4,5,6}$ and by assumption they are independent.) Let $Y$ denote the product of $X_1$ and $X_2$  and $Z$ the product of $X_2$ and $X_3$. Which of the following statements is correct?

option 1. $Y$ and $Z$ are not independent, but $E[Y*Z]=E[Y]*E[Z]$. 
option 2. $Y$ and $Z$ are independent, and $E[Y*Z]=E[Y]*E[Z]$.
option 3. $Y$ and $Z$  are independent, but $E[Y*Z] \neq E[Y]*E[Z]$.
option 4. $Y$ and $Z$  are not independent, and $E[Y*Z] \neq E[Y]*E[Z]$.

My Solution:
$X_1,X_2,X_3$ are variables each taking values   ${1,2,3,4,5,6}$ and each value has a probability $\frac{1}{6}$. 
Now,  
$Y = X_1 * X_2$

$Z = X_2 * X_3$

To find: $E[Y*Z] = E[Y]*E[Z]$  OR $E[Y*Z] \neq E[Y]*E[Z]$

LHS: $E[Y*Z] \\
= E[X_1 * X_2 * X_2 * X_3 ] \\
= E[X_1 * X_2 * X_3 ]    \text{(As in an event $X_2$ can have value  [1,6] only for both the $X_2$  variable above )} \\
= E[X_1] * E[X_2] * E[X_3] \text{(As $X_1$ , $X_2$ and $X_3$ are independent )} $

RHS: $E[Y]*E[Z]  \\
=  E[X_1 * X_2] * E[X_2 * X_3 ] \\
=  E[X_1] * E[X_2] * E[X_2] * E[X_3]   \text{(As $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent and $X_2$ and $X_3$ are independent )}$

∴ $ LHS  \neq RHS $

option 4. $Y$ and $Z$  are not independent, and $E[Y*Z] \neq E[Y]*E[Z]$.

Can someone please tell me if my solution is valid? I know that the answer is surely option 4 but I wanted to know the correct way of proving this problem.

Comment: Why does $E[X_1\times X_2\times X_2\times X_3]=E[X_1\times X_2\times X_3]$?

Comment: Because for example if we have 1=1 , 2=3, 3=6, we will definitely have the 2nd X2's value as 3. It will be the same as the 1st X2's value. So the 2nd X2 will not contribute in the number of permutations of 1,2 and 3 and so the expectation is actually dependent on the permutations of only 1,2 and 3 rather than all of the 1,2, X2 and 3

Comment: Let us look at a smaller simpler example so you can see lulu's point.  Why would you think that $E[X_2\times X_2]$ should equal $E[X_2]$?  You have that $X_2\times X_2$ takes possible values $1,4,9,16,25,36$... while $X_2$ by itself only takes values $1,2,3,4,5,6$... Even without doing the calculations you should be able to see pretty clearly that $E[X_2\times X_2]$ should have a value larger than $E[X_2]$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each of $Y$ and $Z$ could potentially take any of the values $1,2,3,4,5,6,8,10,12,15,16,\dots,36$.  The full list isn't important, but what is important is that $Y$ could potentially take values $1,2,3,4,5$ with positive probability.

Now... If we know that $Z=36$, this directly implies that the results of both $X_2$ and $X_3$ must have been $6$.  Knowing that $Z=36$, we can conclude then that $Y$ must be at least equal to $6$ or greater and that it is impossible for $Y$ to be equal to any of $1,2,3,4,5$.

Therefore, $0=Pr(Y=1\mid Z=36)\neq Pr(Y=1)>0$ and so we know that $Y$ and $Z$ are not independent.  Minimal calculation required here.

---

Now... $E[Y\times Z] = E[X_1\times X_2\times X_2\times X_3] = E[X_1\times X_2^2\times X_3]$

You should be able to reason that since $X_1,X_2,X_3$ are mutually independent random variables that $X_1,X_2^2,X_3$ should also be mutually independent random variables.

We get then since the expectation of a product of independent random variables is equal to the product of the expectations of independent random variables that $E[Y\times Z] = E[X_1]\times E[X_2^2]\times E[X_3]$

Compare this to $E[Y]\times E[Z] = E[X_1]\times E[X_2]\times E[X_2]\times E[X_3]$

Since $E[X_1]$ and $E[X_3]$ are clearly nonzero, these would be equal in the case that $E[X_2^2]=E[X_2]^2$.

But... We remember that $Var(X_2) = E[X_2^2]-E[X_2]^2$ and a zero variance would imply the random variable were constant.  We can clearly see that $X_2$ is not a constant random variable and so we know that $Var(X_2)$ is nonzero as well.  As such we can conclude that $E[Y\times Z]\neq E[Y]\times E[Z]$.  Again, no actual full lengthy calculations needed here.

---

We conclude then that option 4 is the correct answer, that $Y$ and $Z$ are not independent and that $E[Y\times Z]\neq E[Y]\times E[Z]$.

You arrived at the correct answer but by using incorrect calculations.  As mentioned in the comments above, you tried to use the equality $E[X_1\times X_2\times X_2\times X_3] = E[X_1\times X_2\times X_3]$ which simply isn't true in this and many other cases.